# Adding Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to file uploaded using PHP client library

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I'm using the Google Cloud Platform PHP Client library (https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) to upload files to a bucket in my project. I need to be able to grab the file using an AJAX request from another domain so therefore need to add the header

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

I am pulling my hair out trying to figure this out - my Google searches are fruitless. Code sample for reference:

```
$client = new Google_Client();  
$client->setApplicationName("Test");
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();

$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform');

$storage = new Google_Service_Storage($client);
$file_name = "test.txt";
$file_content = "this is a test";

$postbody = array( 
    'name' => $file_name, 
    'data' => $file_content,
    'uploadType' => "media",
    'predefinedAcl' => 'publicRead'
    );

$gsso = new Google_Service_Storage_StorageObject();
$gsso->setName( $file_name );

$result = $storage->objects->insert( "my_bucket", $gsso, $postbody );
```

The file is uploaded correctly and can be viewed in the bucket, but doesn't have the correct headers as I don't know how to add them. In fact, I can't even find a way of adding these headers manually using the Cloud Platform Console. Any pointers appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So I finally found the documentation I needed, it's only possible to set the CORS configuration for the bucket itself (it is not configurable at file level). Instructions to do so using either gsutil or the XML API are [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin#Configuring-CORS-on-a-Bucket)

I created a cors-json-file.json with contents:

```
[
    {
      "origin": ["*"],
      "method": ["*"]
    }
]
```

Then ran

```
gsutil cors set cors-json-file.json gs://my_bucket
```

It's possible to view the existing CORS configuration for your bucket using

```
gsutil cors get gs://my_bucket
```

A full list of configuration options can be found at the [Google Bucket API Reference](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/buckets)

Whether it's an issue with caching or not I'm unsure, but this seems to work only for files added to the bucket *after* you make the CORS configuration change, however I'm happy to be corrected on that

Comment: is it possible to set more headers like Access-Control-Allow-Headers &
Access-Control-Expose-Headers ? If yes how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can also configure CORS with PHP using [StorageClient](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-php/blob/master/src/Storage/StorageClient.php) in [google-cloud-php](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/).

```
$storage = new StorageClient([
    'projectId' => '<project-id>',
    'keyFilePath' => '<path-to-key-file>',
]);

$cors = [
    [
        'maxAgeSeconds' => '3600',
        'method' => ['*'],
        'origin' => ['*'],
        'responseHeader' => ['Content-Type'],
    ],
]

// Creating a bucket with CORS
$storage->createBucket('<bucket-name>', [
    'location' => 'EU',
    'cors' => $cors,
]);

// Updating a bucket
$storage->bucket('<bucket-name>')->update([
    'cors' => $cors,
]);
```

Comment: They have little to no documention/examples of syntax and allowed values.  Your example does not work.